# Lock and Unlock textbox on form1, by command in form2

Tags: c#, textbox

I have two Forms:

```
  Form1
  Form2
```

Whenever I check/uncheck a CheckBox `checkBox1` on `Form2` I want to update `textbox1.Readonly` that is on `Form1`. If *both* `textbox1` and `checkbox1` had been on the ***same Form*** it would be easy go:

```
  private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    textbox1.Readonly = checkBox1.Checked;
  }
```

What shall I do in my case when `textbox1` and `checkbox1` are on ***different*** `Forms`?

Comment: What have you trid ?? Post your code

Comment: by `lock` or `unlock` means `enable` or `disable`? Can you show your code?

Comment: What do you meant by lock or unlock textbox1

Comment: @everyone the form2 doesn't recognize textbox1, because obviously it doesnt exist in that context, i can use a variable to flag it, but that will create another problem, which is, when i enable or disable the checkbox, it will have to reload the program again to enable or disable the readonly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it like this:

```
public partial class Form1: Form {
  ...

  // textBox1 is private (we can't access in from Form2) 
  // so we'd rather create a public property
  // in order to have an access to textBox1.Readonly
  public Boolean IsLocked {
    get {
      return textBox1.Readonly;
    }
    set {
      textBox1.Readonly = value;
    }
  }
}

...

public partial class Form2: Form {
  ...

  private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // When checkBox1 checked state changed,
    // let's find out all Form1 instances and update their IsLocked state
    foreach (Form fm in Application.OpenForms) {
      Form1 f = fm as Form1;

      if (!Object.RefrenceEquals(f, null))
        f.IsLocked = checkBox1.Checked;
    }  

  }
}
```

Comment: Actualy we can access textbox or any control, just change the Modifiers property of the textbox or control to Public instead of private by default
and just access it like Form1.txtMyTxtBox.ReadOnly = true;

Comment: @Jade: Yes, it's possible, but it's also a bad practice to make inner Controls being public. What if you have to change Readonly to Enabled or have to "lock"/"unlock" three textboxes? In my solution all the required changes are localized in a special designed property.

Comment: Yes I know, but you said  // textBox1 is private (we can't access in from Form2)

Comment: Its just an additional information, since there are some situation that make it public is more convinient.

Comment: what does get, and set means? other than that i can't quite get what you wrote on form2 after the checkedstate changed

Comment: I tried to use Jade solution, i set the textobox to public in modifiers and tried to call it using ´Form1.textbox1.ReadOnly = false;´  but i get a error, it says an object reference is required for the non-static field

Comment: @César Amorim: you need Form1 instance, not class; see my code about "foreach (Form fm in Application.OpenForms)..."

Comment: what is exactly a instance? i've heard of it, but i couldnt quite understand, also, why am i getting that strange error even when the textbox1 on form 1 is set to public?

Answer (score 1):

You should use events and delegates.

On Form2, We're create a delegate and event

```
public delegate void OnCheckedEventHandler(bool checkState);
public event OnCheckedEventHandler onCheckboxChecked;

public void checkBox1_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (onCheckboxChecked != null)
        onCheckboxChecked(checkBox1.Checked);
}
```

And on Form1, we're realize this event:

```
void showForm2()
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.onCheckboxChecked += onCheckboxChecked;
    f2.Show();
}

public void onCheckboxChecked(bool checkState)
{
    textBox1.ReadOnly = checkState;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For simplier and more flexible

Form1:

```
public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        Form2 tmpFrm = new Form2();
        tmpFrm.txtboxToSetReadOnly = this.txtMyTextBox; //send the reference of the textbox you want to update
        tmpFrm.ShowDialog(); // tmpFrm.Show();
    }
}
```

FOrm2:

```
public class Form2 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    TextBox _txtboxToSetReadOnly = null;
    public TextBox txtboxToSetReadOnly
    {
        set{ this._txtboxToSetReadOnly = value; }
        get {return this._txtboxToSetReadOnly;}
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if( this._txtboxToSetReadOnly != null)  this._txtboxToSetReadOnly.ReadOnly = checkbox1.Checked;
        /*
         or the otherway 
        if( this._txtboxToSetReadOnly != null) this._txtboxToSetReadOnly.ReadOnly = !checkbox1.Checked;
        */
    }
}
```